# How to get queryset values intersection

Tags: python, django

I try to get values intersection. But function returns a wrong result:

```py
qs1 = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters1).values('brand', 'model')
qs2 = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters2).values('brand', 'model')
result_qs = qs1.intersection(qs2)
```

I see values from `qs1` only in `result_qs`. How can I get intersection of brand-model pairs?

Comment: Are you sure the values in `qs2` are different? It seems like `qs2` is same as `qs1` hence the intersection results

Comment: what do you mean you see values from qs1 only, intersection shows values that exist in both querysets hence they all exist in qs1

Comment: You can often combine the filters into a new filter such that the intersection is done properly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem objects in `qs1` and `qs2` don't intersect. But I want to get same brand and model pairs in both querysets.

Answer (score 1):

```
qs1 = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters1)
qs2 = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters2)
result_qs = qs1.intersection(qs2)
```